# UV calculation on custom 3d mesh

Tags: three.js, opengl-es-2.0, webgl, textures, texture-mapping

After making some research, i didn't find yet any formula that will offer me a way to push faceVertexUvs on my custom mesh (basically countries on top of a sphere), I need to burn world texture on that polygon, and don't know how compute correctly my UV coordinates.

Even with the formula on wikipedia :/ Please need some helps

**The problem** : Calculation for each vertex UV coordinates

Any tips, advices, links are welcome.

I've just found the solution application but not quite sure , texture appears but not a the good point, i get 3 vectors normal which compose a face,and then compute the uv with arctan2, and asin, adding just after 0.5 for correct range [0,1]

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify much about the shape of you countries? Are them an extruded mesh?

You probably are looking for **spherical projection mapping**, which is a well known problem, centuries ago: http://math.rice.edu/~polking/cartography/cart.pdf

Comment: flat polygon , not extruded, nice documentation , gonna check this out thx